# Returning additional table data that is already in the ASP.NET API with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a returned api with a ASP.NET Model in Visual studios. I updated the model by adding a table that has no relationship to my first model except that it's a table with a list of data like, states, or something similar that I want to use for a drop down in Angular.

I currently have

```
app.factory('ComplaintService', ['$http', function ($http){
var urlBase = 'http://localhost:63942/api';
var ComplaintService = {};
ComplaintService.getCities = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase+ '/complaints');
};
return ComplaintService;
}]);
```

How would I implement or extend the factory so that in addition to returning the ComplaintService, I also want it to return AllegationService:

```
return $http.get(urlBase+ '/allegations').
```

I am very confused on when to use a factory or a service. I then want to pass the AllegationService to a 'AllegationList' controller then returns data that will be placed into a drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate factory for allegations. you can just add another factory method to get list of allegations or whatever type of data it is.

```
app.factory('Service', ['$http', function ($http){
  var urlBase = 'http://localhost:63942/api';
  var Service = {};
 Service.getComplaints = function () {
     return $http.get(urlBase+ '/complaints');
 };
 Service.getAllegations = function () {
     return $http.get(urlBase+ '/allegations');
 };
 return Service;
}]);
```